# Where should I place head for a linked list, inside or outside struct?

Tags: c, list, struct, double-pointer

Is it best to keep the head (double pointer) of a linked list inside or outside the structure for the linked list itself?

Comment: Why do you think that `head` of linked list is a double pointer? A `head` of a linked list is just a pointer of type _node_ of that list which point to the first node of the list. If you make it part of _node_ then every node will have its own `head` pointer.

Comment: what is the `structure for the linked list` in your question? What does it contain?

Answer (score 0):

Having a struct to contain the attributes of the linked list allows you to have multiple instances of a linked list at once.

That said, if the head is the only attribute of the linked list —i.e. if you don't maintain a tail or a count, and if you'd don't support per-list custom allocators and deallocators— then there's no point in using a struct. Well, using a struct would make it easier to add those features if you ever decide you need them.